# Why IEqualityComparer<T> has GetHashCode() method?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iequalitycomparer

[IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) in the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` has following methods:

```
bool Equals(T x, T y);
int GetHashCode(T obj);
```

Since this inteface is used to check equality of objects, the first method `Equals` makes sense. But why do we need to implement `GetHashCode` also? Why does it exist in the interface in the first place? When is it needed and why?

I'm using it with [Enumerable.Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) method in the namespace `System.Linq`, and I'm surprised to see that even `GetHashCode()` is getting called, along with `Equals()`. Why? How does `Distinct` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For details on how `Distinct` works (or at least a simple example implementation) see my [Edulinq blog post on it](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct/) (<s>[old - 404](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx)</s>).

To put it simply, a hash code which corresponds to the appropriate equality comparison makes it cheaper to create a set of items. That's useful in a *lot* of situations - such as `Distinct`, `Except`, `Intersect`, `Union`, `Join`, `GroupJoin`, `GroupBy`, `ToLookup` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`GetHashCode` is used in `HashTables`, `Dictionaries` and others to optimize the search. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: I didn't answer that part. Is that really a reason to downvote my post? It's not wrong, because I only answered part of the question.

Comment: @Daniel: I didn't downvote it. :|... +1 from me for partially answering my question. :)

Comment: @Nawaz: Think about how you'd implement Distinct... think about how similar a set is to the keys in a dictionary...

Comment: @Nawaz: I am sorry. Someone did and I interpreted your comment as the explanation, why you did it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : I'm reading your blog. It looks good. Have you explained such thing in your book? Actually, I want to learn such thing in detail. Kindly suggest me where should I start from.

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't go into that aspect in particular detail in the book. You may want to read through the whole of Edulinq though - the last post in the series has a table of contents. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks. I also ordered your book, this edition :  http://www.flipkart.com/depth-2nd-ed-jon-skeet-book-9350040607

Comment: @Nawaz: Cool - hope you enjoy it :)

Comment: For those looking, Skeet's Edulinq series & Table of Contents is available here: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts/

Answer (score 0):

Because the [Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) says:

> It is recommended that any class that overrides Equals also override Object.GetHashCode.

This is because Hashtables etc expects that two objects that are equal have the same hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of IEqualityComparer(Of T) is to allow the use of a comparison method which is semantically different from the default Object.Equals--one which may cause two objects to be considered equal even if Object.Equals would consider them different.  Because equal objects *must* have equal hash codes, and because things which the EqualityComparer's Equals method considers equal but Object.Equals considers unequal might have different hash codes, it is necessary for the the EqualityComparer to use a different hash-coding method.

A more interesting situation exists with IEquatable(Of T).  That is expected never to report two objects as equal if Object.Equals reports them unequal.  For any unsealed class to implement IEquatable(Of T) is dangerous; too bad there's no generic constraint which would forbid the use of unsealed classes.